# Kafka rebalance after consumer no work on some topic

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

kafka server 2.2.1
kafka-clients 0.11.0.2
spring-kafka 1.3.9.RELEASE

consumer.config

```
auto-offset-reset=latest
enable-auto-commit=true
```

one consumer-group consumes three topic (topic1, topic2, topic3)

i consume from server with all 8 pods, and when one pod is killed because of OOM, consumer rebalance. After this, topic1 and topic2 are working, but topic3 not assigned to the consumer, causing topic3 message backlog.

I ask why the problem is happening

Comment: You use very old versions of everything. It is probably hard to answer you after all these years for non-supported Apache Kafka and Spring library for that.

Comment: You can start by adding more logging for onPartitionsAssigned / revoked listeners